# Contenteditable create Element then put cursor inside it on enter and on insert HTML

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, wysiwyg, contenteditable, content-editor

I build my custom wysiwyg with **pure javascript** without other library. I had 1 problerm **once insert HTML to contenteditable** then hit enter to create newline.

I wan't every first child element or text paragraph in my contenteditable wrapped by `div.para` .. Below is some code to explain what I wan't.

```
  <div class="wysiwyg-content" id="post-editor" contenteditable="true">

<div class="para">My first paragraph</div>

<div class="para"><br></div>

<div class="para"><a href=""><img src=""/></a></div>

<div class="para"><figure class="gallery><a href=""><img src=""/></a></figure></div>

<div class="para">or what ever entities wrapped with div.para</div>

  </div>
```

I also use/executed codes below after some event (ex: paste, insert HTML through javascript) to make sure cursor placed at the end of contenteditable with expectations once hit enter to create newline, it does not create unwanted structure/element tag, always create `<div class="para">[cursor placed here]</div>` .

```
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
      el.focus();
      if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
      && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
         var range = document.createRange();
         range.selectNodeContents(el);
         range.collapse(false);
         var sel = window.getSelection();
         sel.removeAllRanges();
         sel.addRange(range);
      } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
         var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
         textRange.moveToElementText(el);
         textRange.collapse(false);
         textRange.select();
      }
   }

// I used code below to executed AFTER insert HTML to conteneditable.
placeCaretAtEnd( document.getElementById("post-editor") );
```

I think javascript above not enough to complete my goal. Because, after insert some HTML through javascript to contenteditable THEN HIT ENTER (cursor look at end of my contenteditable); it will be create element and follow last tag of element INSIDE `div.para`. ex: insert `<div class="para"><figure class="gallery><a href=""><img src=""/></a></figure></div>` html, then hit enter will become `<div class="para"><figure class="gallery><br>[possible cursor here]</div>` . What I wan't everytime hit enter contenteditable create new element `<div class="para">[then cursor placed here]</div>` .

How to do that with Pure Javascript? Thanks in advance.